# getOrDefault for Hashmap with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

i'm using this code to compute the in going edges of a node in a graph

```
for (Edge newEdge : edges) {
        // Ingoing edges

        if (inGoingEdges.containsKey(newEdge.destinationnode)) {

            //System.out.println("All good");

        } else {

            inGoingEdges.put(newEdge.destinationnode, new ArrayList<Edge>());

        }

        ArrayList<Edge> inEdges = inGoingEdges.get(newEdge.destinationnode);

        if (inEdges == null) {

            inEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
            inEdges.add(newEdge);
            inGoingEdges.put(newEdge.sourcenode, inEdges);

        }

        else {

            if (!inEdges.contains(newEdge)) {

                inEdges.add(newEdge);
                inGoingEdges.put(newEdge.sourcenode, inEdges);

            }

        }
```

where inGoingEdges is the following HashMap :

```
private HashMap<Node,ArrayList<Edge>> inGoingEdges = new HashMap<Node,ArrayList<Edge>>();
```

At some point of my code i use the following function :  **graph.getIncomingEdges(firstNode)** but for some nodes there is no ArrayList that matches to some nodes and it returns a nullpoint error.

How can i use the getorDefault function correctly in order to fix the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want `getOrDefault`, because that doesn't add the new list. What you probably want is `computeIfAbsent`. You provide it with a function that takes the key as argument and returns a value if none exists yet. If there already is a value, that is returned and the function is ignored. You can also use that in the code you provided to make it all less verbose:

```
// Ingoing edges
ArrayList<Edge> inEdges = inGoingEdges.computeIfAbsent(newEdge.destinationnode, k -> new ArrayList<>());

// inEdges will never be null
if (!inEdges.contains(newEdge)) {
    inEdges.add(newEdge);
    inGoingEdges.put(newEdge.sourcenode, inEdges);
}
```

Comment: for (Node firstNode : graph.nodes.values()) {

    double tempSum = 0;

    for (Edge tempEdge : graph.getIncomingEdges(firstNode)) {

     //tempSignal.tempMap.getOrDefault(tempEdge.getSource(), initPagerank);
     
     tempSum = tempSum + tempSignal.getNodeScore(tempEdge.getSource())
       * (1 / (graph.getOutgoingEdges(tempEdge.getSource()).size()));
     
    }

Comment: This is the part where i call the function that i mentioned. The error occurs in the part that i write tempSignal.getNodeScore(tempEdge.getSource()) where it says that the hash map is null . I will provide you with the code for the signal object in the next comment.

Comment: public class GraphSignal {

 protected HashMap<Node, Double> tempMap;

 public GraphSignal(HashMap<Node, Double> tempMap) {
  this.tempMap = tempMap;
 }

 public double getNodeScore(Node tempNode) {
  return tempMap.get(tempNode);
 }

Comment: Your solution didnt seem to work but that's maybe on me cause i didnt provide you with the above info? Do you have anything else in mind that maybe could solve the problem?

Comment: `tempSignal.getNodeScore` can use `getOrDefault`: `return tempMap.getOrDefault(tempNode, 0)`. Note that when you use `tempMap.get`, the NullPointerException is not necessarily caused because `tempMap` is `null`, but more likely it's the auto-unboxing of the `null` result of `tempMap.get` to a `double` that causes the NPE.